# I can't understand this code? Is it normal or I'm not ready?

Tags: c, operators

These are some lines of an example code in a C tutorial book that I can't understand.

I have already learned 
operators, program structure, variables, I/O, decision making & loops, array, strings ..., functions and right now I am at chapter 6 pointers.

```
void check(char *a,char *b, int (*cmp)(const char *,char *)); // this one
//int cmp(char * , char *);
int main()
{
    char s1[80],s2[80];
    int (*p)(const char *,const char *); //  and this one



if(!(cmp)(a,b)) //and this
```

(this code is not complete)

Is this normal?  Should I use a different source?

Comment: They are two pointers to functions.  The syntax is a bit weird, but what's required if you need a pointer to a function.  The notation `if (!(cmp)(a, b))` is an invocation of the function identified by the function pointer `cmp`.  The parentheses around `(cmp)` are not actually needed — they would be if it was written `if (!(*cmp)(a, b))`, which would also work.

Answer (score 2):

```
void check(char *a,char *b, int (*cmp)(const char *,char *)); // this one
```

This is a function which takes 3 parameters,

1. a character pointer
2. another character pointer
3. a function pointer. The function in question returns an int and takes 2 character pointers as arguments.

The next line,

```
int (*p)(const char *,const char *);
```

This is a function pointer `p`. The function returns an int and takes 2 character pointers as arguments.

```
if(!(cmp)(a,b))
```

`cmp` is not defined in the scope here, but I am assuming this line is inside the function `check`. In that case, you are calling the function `cmp` with the arguments `a` and `b` which are presumably character pointers.

Comment: thanks , but i really wonted to know if its normal for me not to understand this things or i'm learning  C wrong

Comment: @capHossein12DarthVader If you are just learning pointers then function pointers are a more advanced topic. You should understand the details and intricacies of pointers. StackOverflow does not generally recommend any books for learning C, but there are a few older answers which can give some information.